# Why the Python .append() appends two values, instead of one in a list?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I have two lists and one dictrionary:

```
a = ['Foo bar', 'Hello!']
b = {'Foo': 'bar', 'Hello': 'foo'}
c = []
```

I'm trying to replace **Foo** with **bar** and **Hello** with **foo** in every `a` element and append the new values to `c`.

Hovewer, this code gives the following output:

```
for i in a:
    for entry in b:
        c.append(i.replace(entry, b.get(entry)))

print(c)
```

```
['bar bar', 'Foo bar', 'Hello!', 'foo!']
```

#### Expected output:

```
['bar bar', 'foo!']
```

I was expecting the `c` list to contain only the modified values, not the original ones.

Am I missing something?

Comment: You run 2x2 times, so you should expect 4 items to be appended.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem you're having is that you're always appending for every value in the dictionary, you should build up a string and then append it after checking the dictionary. You can also use the dictionaries `items` to avoid getting the value seperate from the key

```
for i in a:
    new_val = i
    for key, val in b.items():
        new_val = new_val.replace(key, val)
    c.append(new_val)
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
a = ['Foo bar', 'Hello!']
b = {'Foo': 'bar', 'Hello': 'foo'}
c = []
for i in a:
    c.append(i)
    for entry in b:
        c[-1] = c[-1].replace(entry, b.get(entry))

print(c)
```

Output:

```
['bar bar', 'foo!']
```

The issue with your current code is that you append a new item each time you replace - you only want to edit the last item.

Comment: Have changed to fix - missed reassignment :)